# Net::SSH with non unix/linux host?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use the Net::SSH library to login and manage a host that supports ssh. It is a piece of telecom equipment and so speaks TL1. I seem to be able to log in successfully, but when I try to ssh.exec something, it aborts saying it could not execute command. Here is my simple code:

```
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start('10.204.121.192', 'password', :password => "password") do |ssh|
  ssh.exec("INH-MSG-ALL;")
end
```

If i point the same code at a Linux server and provide a command such as "ls -l /", it works fine. What I am wondering is, can I use this ssh library? Do I need to use another command instead of exec?

This is the error output:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:322:in `block (2 levels) in exec': could not execute command: "INH-MSG-ALL;" (RuntimeError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:597:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:597:in `do_failure'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:586:in `channel_failure'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:456:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:213:in `preprocess'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:197:in `process'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `block in loop'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:110:in `close'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/net-ssh-2.2.1/lib/net/ssh.rb:194:in `start'
from ssh_test.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it works fine when you login in the shell manually.

To understand what is the difference when you connect through net/ssh collect output of `env` command in both cases and compare.

That most probably you'll see a difference that will lead you to a solution or at least will give you dirty trick.

UPDATE. (Not working)

```
Net::SSH.start('10.204.121.192', 'password', :password => "password") do |ssh|
   ssh.open_channel do |channel|
        channel.on_data do |ch, data|
          puts "got data: #{data.inspect}"
        end
        channel.send_data("INH-MSG-ALL;\n")
   end
end
```

**UPDATE2. (Working)**

```
Net::SSH.start('10.204.121.192', 'password', :password => "password") do |ssh|
   ssh.open_channel do |channel|
        channel.send_channel_request "shell"
        channel.on_data do |ch, data|
          puts "got data: #{data.inspect}"
        end
        channel.send_data("INH-MSG-ALL;\n")
   end
end
```

Comment: Okay, I am not quite sure what you mean the "env" command, in ruby? or on the host I am ssh'ed into? If the later, there is no env command on the device I ssh into as it only speaks TL1. I did try printing out the ENV has in ruby using pp to see if something there changes, and it does not.

Comment: There is another method `send_data`. Try it.

Comment: And don't forget `\n` in the end because most probably it is some binary that spawns on ssh connection so that you're actually speaking not to a shell but to some other binary in/out/err.

Comment: Hmm, there is only send_message for Net::SSH::Connection::Session and I tried this. It does not abort, but nothing seems to happen, I don't know how to read the output, if there is any. I did see send_data for a channel, so I tried this as well `channel = ssh.open_channel do |ch|
    ch.send_data("INH-MSG-ALL;\n")
  end
` but this just hangs

Comment: hmm, this also hangs, this is my code: `channel = ssh.open_channel do |ch|
    channel.on_data do |ch, data|
      puts "got data: #{data.inspect}"
    end
    channel.send_data("INH-MSG-ALL;\n")
end`

Comment: Also, just tried your second update and also hangs: `ssh.open_channel do |channel|
        channel.on_data do |ch, data|
          puts "got data: #{data.inspect}"
        end
        channel.send_data("INH-MSG-ALL;\n")
   end
`

Comment: That must be the end of story. just close the channel `channel.close` when you're done and ssh will close then. If you don't like an asynchronous approach, you can fake some synchronous method like `response = channel.send_message("do something;\n")`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks forker for your updates),

One more thing,

from your code how to make this

```
puts "got data: #{data.inspect}"
```

to output data for each command sent to the shell ?

Does this code wait for each command to complete?

Thanks.