# Does Ruby Net::SSH work on a non-Unix/Linux host?

Tags: ruby, ssh

I have a similar issue as the prior one [Net::SSH with non unix/linux host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921421/netssh-with-non-unix-linux-host)

I am trying to connect to a device (vyatta) and do some configurations. If I use exec, it will raise an exception like "invalid command". I guess that is because the environment issue. What I am looking for is a way to just send a string to server to simulate the manual way, I thought send_data could do it, but seems like not works. 
Any suggestions?  Thanks

```
@ssh_conn = Net::SSH.start( host, user, :password => pass ) do |ssh|
 ssh.open_channel do |channel|
   p "open channel"
  channel.send_data("show date\n")
 end
 end
```

Paste another useful link here, seems vyatta uses vbash
[Paramiko "Invalid command" when trying non-standard command for Vyatta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864552/paramiko-invalid-command-when-trying-non-standard-command-for-vyatta)

Comment: Can you connect to the device at all with plain old ssh (on command line)? It might help if you say what device you are talking about.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864552/paramiko-invalid-command-when-trying-non-standard-command-for-vyatta   the device is vyatta, seems I found another clue in the link I pasted, it is using vbash. So the question is how can I run the command in vbash env with net::ssh

Comment: I gave up to use expect shell as a work around, do not want to spend a lot of time on the vbash compatibility. But it is still welcome if anyone can provide a solution